# Why flex scanner is slow when matching NUL characters?

Tags: lex, flex-lexer

I have a lexer written by someone else, who generated it using flex. It works, but in a sample which contains a string literal, and a lot of NUL characters in it, the scanning is very slow.

After some googling I found this paragraph in the flex docs, that states this, without reason:

> A final note: flex is slow when matching NUL's, particularly when a
>   token contains multiple NUL's. It's best to write rules which match
>   short amounts of text if it's anticipated that the text will often
>   include NUL's.

What's flex's problem with NUL characters?

Comment: Perhaps it uses it as a string termination character (which is normal in C), and needs to escape it in some way.

Comment: Moreover, what will yytext contain?

Answer (score 0):

(The question is answered in the comments from @Rhymoid and @Kaz. The are copied here. See also [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

Perhaps it uses it as a string termination character (which is normal in C), and needs to escape it in some way. Moreover, what will yytext contain?